# Fill between 3D curves in `ParametricPlot3D`

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a pair of 3D parametric curves:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {{x*Sin[x], x*Cos[x], -((2*x)/3)}, {1.15*x*Sin[x], 1.15*x*Cos[x], -((2*x)/3)}},
 {x, 0, (11/4)*Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker[Blue], Darker[Blue]}
]
```

[image]

I would like to fill the 2D region between the two curves, in order to create a locally flat 'solid'. How do I go about this?

I'm guessing the the best bet might be `ParametricRegion` - but I can't figure out how to make it work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few additional alternatives:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{v x Sin[x], v x Cos[x], -2 x /3}, 
  {x,  0, (11/4)*Pi}, {v, 1, 1.15}, 
  PlotStyle -> Darker[Blue],  Mesh -> None,  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{v x Sin[x], v x Cos[x], -2 x /3}, 
 {x, 0, (11/4)*Pi}, {v, 0, 1.15}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 100,
 MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, Mesh -> {{1}}, MeshShading -> {None, Darker@Blue}]
```

> same picture

```
ParametricPlot3D[{v x Sin[x], v x Cos[x], -2 x /3}, 
 {x, 0, (11/4)*Pi}, {v, 0, 1.15}, 
 PlotStyle -> Darker[Blue],  PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None,
 RegionFunction -> (1 <= #5 <= 1.15 &)]
```

> same picture

Comment: With thanks to you both, I am ticking the second answer, as this produces a smoother curve. I appreciate both replies, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way is to let `ParametricPlot` linearly interpolate between the two curves:

```
f1 = {x*Sin[x], x*Cos[x], -((2*x)/3)};
f2 = {1.15*x*Sin[x], 1.15*x*Cos[x], -((2*x)/3)};
ParametricPlot3D[{
  lambda f1 + (1 - lambda) f2
  },
 {x, 0, (11/4)*Pi},
 {lambda, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> Darker[Blue],
 Mesh -> None
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It seems we had the same idea. :) (+1 of course.)